# WEKA cross validation datasets export

Tags: export, weka, cross-validation

I am using WEKA 3.7.11. I am using the J4.8 classification method with the 10-fold cross validation option. Is there a way to export/save the datasets produced by the cross validation in order to use them as input to other methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish have data set containing columns with predictions of your model have a look here:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions
Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

I think Weka allows you to save the results for the datasets (10 sets of results for 10 fold CV) but not the datasets themselves. In order to have your datasets in hand, you can first create them according to my video tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyHpHOn7R8Y). Then you need to use the k datasets you produce to simulate a k-fold CV. I know it is not a good solution, but still this is the way that solved my problems.